# Does turning lock screen passcode off disable iCloud password saving?

Tags: ios, icloud, password, screen-lock

I'm not an iOS user myself, but my mother has an iPad and iPhone, and I'm the family tech support (I've been a software engineer for almost 40 years).

Her iPhone frequently asks for her iCloud password. Shouldn't this be saved automatically in the settings, so she doesn't have to keep entering it?

She has the lock screen password disabled, does this prevent saving the iCloud password?

It also hasn't backed up to iCloud in months (I just did a manual backup). On the backup screen it says that it should backup automatically when it's plugged into a power source and locked. Does the lack of a lock screen password mean that it won't backup automatically, since it's never actually locked?

I just turned off the lock screen passcode on her iPad, is it going to start doing the same thing?

Comment: I have never tested your scenario - but as the iPhone can access anything once unlocked, including your bank account, then removing the passcode these days is madness - the only secured item left is the iCloud account itself. The device is never going to remember the actual iCloud a/c password permanently [it does for a while, but periodically needs re-confirming] for security reasons, same as it wants the passcode periodically, even if you have a thumbprint. Presumably, no passcode, no thumbprint, it's going to ask more often.

Comment: There's no bank account in her iphone.

Comment: ... but there **could** be. Enabling users to expose their machine to the first bad actor who walks by is part of the current issue the world is facing. "I don't want a passcode" is a behaviour that the user needs to be protected from, to the best of the major companies' ability.

Comment: My parents, in their mid-80s, have been impressed with the need for passcode & non-trivial password. OK, I set all their devices, across 2 accounts & 5 devices, to the same passcode & password [& all their recovery avenues lead via me, including things such as their email server], so they don't need to differentiate - but overall, it's considerably better than nothing at all.

Comment: As a computer professional I understand all this. But she's really technically challenged, and having to enter passwords drives her crazy. She has to have everything written down for her, and she loses track of them. And then if something changes, she's lost. I'm just trying to make things easier for her.

Comment: I fully understand, my parents have the first hints of dementia, so I have to keep the patterns simple & related to major events in their lives; but removing security from one area is going to make the others tighten up, if the big players such as Apple are going to protect their users' data & their own reputation for being 'unhackable'. Better to use 1956 & myTown23 [number as 'year I married' or 'house I grew up in' rather than birthday] than nothing at all.

Comment: A wild idea [which I've considered for my own future] A photo of you & your mum, on the mantelpiece in her living room. You're holding a chalkboard with the passcode & password. That would take a rather more disturbing 'bad actor' scenario than you would be reasonably concerned with in ordinary circumstances.

Comment: This is all interesting, but I don't need to be convinced of the value of passwords. I'm about to turn her hard-to-read slips of paper where things like her wifi password, bank password, etc. are written down into a nicely printed one for her. I just want to know how the iOS devices work in this regard.

Comment: Is it an option to purchase a newer device, one with either Touch ID or Face ID?  They won't need to memorize the passcode.  I'm not 100% positive but I thought iOS doesn't save the iCloud password if there's no lock screen PIN active.

Comment: If it will change things she's already used to, I'm not eager to get her anything new. She was practically in tears when I upgraded her Mac from Snow Leopard to El Cap last year, because the scroll bar arrows went away and her favorite game was no longer compatible.